# How to pass a value from shell script to email notification plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have jenkins job with below setup and need your inputs in passing value from one task to another.

I have written shell script in 'Post Build Task' step and it will result in a value which i need to use in email notification.
Both the tasks are in Post Build steps.
How can i pass the value from shell script to email notification plugin.

Any help would really appreciate.

Thanks,
Srini

Comment: can you post a relevant, even if broken, Jenkinsfile snippet?

Comment: Sure, I am capturing code coverage in a variable ($itcoverage) through shellscript and like to send that in email notification.

#!/bin/bash
pwd
function jsonValue() {
KEY=$1
num=$2
awk -F"[,:}]" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/'$KEY'\042/){print $(i+1)}}}' | tr -d '"' | sed -n ${num}p
}
utcoverage=`curl -s -H "Accept:application/json" -X GET "http://sonar.vip.yyy.com/api/resources?resource=service&metrics=coverage" | jsonValue frmt_val`
echo "Integration Test Coverage : "$itcoverage

Comment: Is this in a pipeline or freestyle project?